# Best Practices for Error and Access Log Files

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, logfiles

I got a server which has at the moment a lot of access and error logs. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Nginx.

My question is what would be the best practices to keep this files under control but not loose track of what is going on? What you be the best balance? Should I use Ubuntu crons or the Nginx can handle that itself? Could you indicate any good documentation?

Answer (score 0):

A good option it could be to use a third-party service to store and parse logs for you (for example logentries.com).

If you want to preserve privacy on your log's content and you are worried that the content is sent to someone you don't know, you can self-host a similar tool like logstash.net

If you like to manage them in old-fashion way you can configure syslog to push logs on a remote machine where you are confortable to check them.

Speaking about nginx log a little trick I usually do is to configure access and error log on per-server basis, so if I have my nginx serving foo.com and bar.org I usually store them in

```
/var/www/foo.com/logs/ [for foo.com domain]
/var/www/bar.org/logs/ [for bar.org domain]
```

In this way I have them separated and I can check what is happening on each domain independently